# jQuery - Read data from text file with .get/.load - force reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load data from a web server with jQuery. I'm uploading a file to a web server, put the response (which is containing a link) to an iframe and read this link with .get(). When I now upload another file, which leads to the same filename but changed contents, .get() does not read the content correctly on the first try, but reliable on the second. .load() should do basically the same, but does not reload the file no matter how often I re-upload the file.

Is there a chance to force the reload of the changed file?

```
var linkToTextFile = 'http://www.myserver.com/myTextFile.txt';

$.get(linkToTextFile, function(data){
    alert("Data:" + data); //content changes on second try
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to append a random GET parameter to your text file's URL :

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
var linkToTextFile = 'http://www.myserver.com/myTextFile.txt?t=' + timestamp;
```

This way it will force the browser to reload the file.

Comment: I already tried this before, but somehow this does not work either. I get the same behavior as without the '?t=<timestamp>'.

Comment: Try with `$.post()` instead of `$.get()`, maybe it will be better... I'm pretty sure it is a browser setting issue on your side if the timestamp trick is not working...

Comment: Okay, I was trying the post, but it didn't work either. I was playing around a bit more, but I just can't figure out the error.